# Browser Plugin?

Tags: javascript, browser, user-interface

I want to design a system where user can give a specific font size from a settings and whole site will be changed and every writing would be of that font size. Now i think I have to develop a browser plugin. however, if any of you can suggest that without using browser plugin i can do that, then definitely I want to know that. [ here user will be able to modify the site from the browser ,user has nothing to do with the existing sites coding what so ever]

Comment: Control+Scroll Wheel isn't suitable? Also, most browsers allow for client-side CSS rules (CSS files you can have applied to every webpage you visit).

Answer (score 2):

Please don't develop a plug-in just for that.

Unless you're working with really old browsers (IE6 and such) that would not scale fonts specified in certain units, all modern browsers have menu and keyboard settings to change the font size. Let the users use those.

You can also use a bit of Javascript to display "bigger/smaller" buttons somewhere and either replace a stylesheet file or adjust the default font size of the `<body>` element and have the rest of the elements derive percentages from it.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I want to do as I mentioned,I dont want to use to zoom or font changing option from the browser itself. Rather I want to change any site locally. Is that possible?

Comment: Usually in the browser settings, you can set the default zoom or the default stylesheet. This would apply to all sites.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about other way to do it,but anyway plugin won't help you.

See this excellent article: http://colonelpanic.net/2010/08/browser-plugins-vs-extensions-the-difference/

You mean a browser extension. As you can see in the article- if you want to write an extension to IE use BHO. For Firefox see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School